# Why is TSFEL feature extraction not iterating through the data frame properly?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm using TSFEL to iterate through a dataframe 4148 rows long with 6 columns total where 1 of the columns splits into 3 sublists for all 4148 rows. The code I utilized is as follows:

```
feature_list = []
for index in df_0_B['data_lw']:
    testing = tsfel.time_series_features_extractor(cfg, index)
    feature_list.append(testing)

print(testing)
```

I'm expecting for it to iterate and extract features for each row and store them into another data frame to be used for training and testing. I'm only getting 1 row with 120 columns after running feature extraction.